# mySQl vs. PHP (and Twig), partly incomplete date, wrong rendering (2017-01-00 as Dec 31, 2016)

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am developing a (basic) Symfony web app. 
I have a entity with a  `@var \DateTime  @ORM\Column(name="Data", type="date")` property, and I need to store incomplete dates as `2017-01-00` and `2017-00-00`. So far so good.

The issue is that `{{ myentity.mydata|localizeddate('medium', 'none', 'en' ) }}`  renders them as `Dec 31, 2016` and resp. `Nov 30, 2016`;  instead I would like to get just `Jan, 2017` and resp. `2017`.

Am i doing something wrong, or is twig unable to handle such kind of cases? do you see a quick way out?

note: the issue is not `localizeddate`,  `date('d M Y')` misrenders too.

EDIT

Now, I do think the issue goes back to mysql and PHP. Please check the following screenshots, they show how php converts `2017-00-00` to `Nov 30, 2016`. I see somebody has a way out ([this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560108/formatting-partial-unknown-dates-with-datetime-from-a-database)), but I am not sure how to use  the latter within my Symfony app.

[image: mysql]

[image: php]

where `formatDatabaseDate($date, $delimiter = '/')` is from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560108/formatting-partial-unknown-dates-with-datetime-from-a-database)

[image: results]

thks mario

Answer (score 0):

I've created a twigfiddle to show you that the filter `date('M, Y')` should work for you:

https://twigfiddle.com/155jb9

This the code I used:

```
{% set mydate = '2017-07-31 09:46:10' %}
{{ mydate|date('M, Y') }}
```

Although this doesn't address the issue of `storing` as incomplete dates. To do that you need to show us a bit of your code.

If you have to use the [Intl Extension](http://twig-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intl.html), then I think the 5th argument is the date format. Twigfiddle doesn't have that capability. So I think your code would be something like this:

```
{{ myentity.mydata|localizeddate('none', 'none', 'en', 'GMT', 'M, Y' ) }}
```

maybe you can try that?

---

EDIT #2 - based on comments

You should have made you post clearer if that's what you wanted, however I updated my twigfiddle (new one) to handle your requirements. You would code it like so:

```
{% if day == '00' and month == '00' %}
    {{ mydate|date('Y') }}
{% elseif day == '00' and month != '00' %}
    {{ mydate|date('M, Y') }}
{% else %}
    {{ mydate|date('D M Y') }}
{% endif %}
```

Where you just use slice to get the `day` and `month` values as needed. See this new twigfiddle to try it out. Change the `set mydate` string to see the if statements working:

https://twigfiddle.com/r9m3j3

---

EDIT #3 - based on comments

In twig you would format and slice like so:

```
{{ myDate|date('Y-M-D H:I:S')|slice(5,2) }}
```

Comment: Thks for your reply, but I did not explain myself. I have hundreds of dates, most of them complete, some incomplete (2017-01-00, 2017-00-00)). I need to render complete ones in a complete way D M Y; incomplete ones as just M,Y (when D is 00)  or just Y (when both D and M are 00).

Comment: Added EDIT #2. Try it out. You might have to modify your code as per your design.

Comment: @ Alvin thsk for your help. Yes of course, although I hoped it was hard coded within twig.  Maybe a last point: do you know why 2017-01-00 is rendered as Dec 31, 2016; 2017-00-00 as Nov 30, 2016, instead that say  both as Jan 1, 2017? thsk

Comment: What is the actual date value in the database? Or maybe it's using a different time zone, and thus because its Jan 1, because the timezone difference its the day earlier - check that out. Also, did my answer solve your question? If so, give either an upvote or checkmark.

Comment: @ Alvin, sorry for late reply. Actually, your fiddle works because you pass a string to slice. If I try to pass a datetime entity, I get a "Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string" error. If I try  something like  myDate.format(dmY)|slice(5,2)   I am back to the initial issue. Do I need  a toString method for datetime entities? How exactly?

Comment: I updated my post mario. The twig docs on [date are here](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/date.html). You just need to format the date in the exact same way and it should work.

Comment: @ Alvin, your last edit does not work for me:  when you filter by date('Y-M-D H:I:S') you lose the 00's. Anyway, it is not a issue with twig, it goes back to the underlying php (I believe). See my screenshots.